# opencv gpu cannot load feature type haar

Tags: opencv, gpu, cascade-classifier

I am trying to use opencv gpu based cascade classifier. Here is a snapshot where I try to load the cascade

```
gpu::CascadeClassifier_GPU cascade_gpu;
if(!cascade_gpu.load(HAARCASCADE_FRONTALFACE3))
return 0;
```

I am getting the following error when I try to load
Unspecified error (The node does not represent a user object (unknown type?)) in cvRead, file /Users/ashok/ivsvn/3rdparty/trunk/opencv-2.4.8/modules/core/src/persistence.cpp, line 4991

Here is the header of the cascade file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<opencv_storage>
<cascade>
  <stageType>BOOST</stageType>
  <featureType>HAAR</featureType>
  <height>20</height>
  <width>20</width>
  <stageParams>
    <boostType>GAB</boostType>
    <minHitRate>9.9949997663497925e-01</minHitRate>
    <maxFalseAlarm>3.4999999403953552e-01</maxFalseAlarm>
    <weightTrimRate>9.4999999999999996e-01</weightTrimRate>
    <maxDepth>1</maxDepth>
    <maxWeakCount>1000</maxWeakCount></stageParams>
  <featureParams>
    <maxCatCount>0</maxCatCount>
    <featSize>1</featSize>
    <mode>ALL</mode></featureParams>
  <stageNum>18</stageNum>
  <stages> ...
```

I have a similar cascade file that is trained with

LBP that works with the gpu load. 
Any clue on this issue?